# Unable to use Microsoft Office

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have been having issues opening Microsoft Office Apps for Enterprise on a Surface Laptop 3 running Windows 10 Version 20H2. I also had this issue in previous Windows versions such as Version 1909. I have tried using both Quick Repair and Online Repair to repair Microsoft Office, I have tried a full uninstall and reinstall, I have ensured that I am installing it with the correct Microsoft account. When I try to open any Office application such as Word, PowerPoint, Excel, etc from the Windows Search bar, I don't get any response, but if I try running it as an administrator or from File Explorer, I get a permission error "Windows cannot open the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item", but I am the only admin on my computer. I have also tried running `sfc` and `dism` to ensure that the problem is not with Windows. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Running Antivirus?

Comment: Try running a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Use the second web link on the page and run in place.

Comment: If all else fails, try an alternative office suite, such as free LibreOffice.

Comment: Check this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-when-you-try-to-install-update-or-start-a-program-or-file-46361133-47ed-6967-c13e-e75d3cc29657.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, I am running Microsoft Defender Antivirus, although disabling it doesn't help fix the problem.

Comment: @ErinDing none of the suggestions in the article seemed to help. I already had full control over the files and I don't think it's corruption because as I mentioned, I completely reinstalled Office.

Comment: I wasn't counting that one sir ;)  I guess I should have made my question more clear.